# input file type

Tags: html

In many html tutorials they show input file type and the result being a button choose file type which when you click it pops up dialog box to select files from your hard drive,but when i run the same code i get the text input box with the button on the side saying browse.I want to get the same result how do i do that?Here is the code

```
enter code here <input type="file" id="flupload" name="fileupload/>
```

Comment: Can you please link to one of those tutorials so we know what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: tell us the links to the tutorials or provide with some screenshots.

Comment: If you try this in Google chrome.. you will not get the text box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every browser has its own file input element style. A text box with a "Browse" button is the style your browser of choice is using. You cannot change that.

[image: file inputs]

Comment: +1 Whilst it is true you can not change it, you can replace it with your own in a hacky way (or use one that uses Flash).

Comment: You can make it invisible and put it on top of a button you make yourself. I have done this a few times to make designers happy.

Comment: Yes, you can hack around it, but that's violating user expectations and possibly accessibility if you're doing it wrong. Designing for the web you first and foremost need to get over the idea that everything looks identical to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The display of the file input type depends on your browser so to get the other display you would have to switch browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to make with a little CSS ... Just make the real file input element completely opaque, then position that right on top of the dummy. It may take some JS to make hovers, though.

Here are some tutorials:
http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom 
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Hope those help!